# Finding the total number of repeat strings in a string C++ -- without maps

Tags: c++, string

My program has to find the total number of repeated strings in a string. I cannot use maps or built in string functions other than length()

> Example : string input = "Hello hello Hello"
>
> Hello : 2

I am hitting a roadblock with separating the strings by the spaces and reading them. I can't figure out what to write to make that happen.

What I want to do is create a temp string to compare to the next string and if they are equal to store it in a vector and then read from the vector at the end.

What function could I use to do that?

Here is my code below :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector <string> mystring;
int numberString(string const&in)
{
    int total = 0;
    char temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++)
    {
        temp = in[i];
        if (temp == ' ')
            total++;
    }
    total++;
    return total;
}
void findRepeats(string const &in)
{
    int numberOfStrings = numberString(in);
    int asciiArray[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        asciiArray[i] = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    string temp = "blank";
    while (numberOfStrings != counter)
    {
        temp = in;
    }
}
int main()
{
    string input;
    cout << "Enter a string : ";
    getline(cin, input);
    findRepeats(input);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What if the string you are looking for (as opposed to the one you are looking *in*) has a space in it?

Comment: Then the space would separate them into two strings. One before the space and one after it. What I don't understand is how to say temp = the input string up to but not including the space. Then mystring.push_back(temp if it's not already in here).

Comment: So if string input is "a a b b a a b b", then searching for "a b" would yield what?

Comment: temp would be set to a. then compared to the next bit which is a so a goes in the vector and the counter increments then temp is set to a again a is already in the vector so the counter increments again but it is not pushed again. Next b is set to temp and so on and so forth. at the end a : 4 b : 4 is the final result.

Comment: @Hikari: I gave an answer based on maps, and your reaction is only to append "-- without maps" to your title?... not very nice. Where does this constraint come from, and how do you suppose to name duplicates without storing them?

Comment: @davidhigh I don't mean to be rude I simply forgot to add that stipulation. This is a program for a class assignment and that's the rule. Mapping isn't something that has been covered yet so if I apply them I'm sure I'd lose points. I do believe mapping is the best way to do this because the concept of what a map is built for matches the scope of this assignment perfectly. I have no idea how to store it which is why I've been working on it using a vector and also why I cam here seeking advice. I'm not saying your way is wrong or bad it just goes against the specs of my assignment.

Comment: @Hikari: you can use an array (`std::vector`) instead of a map. Regarding the edit: do it if you forgot it, but it would be fair to leave a comment under my answer.

Comment: @davidhigh your right that is fair. As someone asking for help I should give feedback or ask additional questions on all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward way to count substrings in a whitespace-separated string is to insert them into a map and and track the occurrence count:

```
std::string input = "Hello hello Hello";
std::istringstream iss(input);
std::map<std::string, size_t> m;

std::string temp;
while(iss >> temp)
{
    auto it = m.find(temp);
    if(it != std::end(m))
    {
        ++(it->second);
    }
    else
    {
        m.insert(std::make_pair(temp, 0));
    }
}

//display counts as:
for(auto it = std::begin(m); it != std::end(m); ++it)
{
    std::cout<<"string \""<<it->first<<"\" was found "<<it->second<<" times"<<std::endl;
}
```

The code is untested.

Comment: I don't quite understand what stringstream iss does in this case, does it take input as a parameter?

Comment: @Hikari: I don't get why you've accepting this... you said you don't want a map? The `stringstream` parses the string by whitespaces and inserts the substrings into `temp`.

Comment: I'm accepting it because I did some changes to it and got it work it put me on the right track with how to write a good answer. I just didn't get how sstream  worked its easy to translate it into a vector. One last question. How did you make stringstream and temp in a gray box like that? I've been trying to do that for awhile but it never works :-(

Comment: :-) See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), section "inline code". In short: put those ` around your code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code finds duplicate words as long as all words are seperated by a single space:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string input = "Hello hello hello";

    map<string, int> wordCount;

    for (string::size_type p = 0; p < input.size(); )
    {
        const auto p2 = input.find_first_of(' ', p);

        const auto word = input.substr(p, (p == string::npos) ? string::npos : (p2 - p));
        ++wordCount[word];

        if (p2 == string::npos)
            break;

        p = p2 + 1;
    }

    for (const auto& it : wordCount)
        if (it.second > 1)
            std::cout << it.first << " " << it.second << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Be aware that this code does not only find consecutive duplicates. So "a b a" outputs 'a 2'.

The line ++wordCount[word] increments the counter for the word or initializes it to 1 if 'word' is not already found in the map (This is working because the template initializes the value with int() which is guaranteed to initialize to zero)

At the end you get a map with an entry for every unique word (first=Word, second=count)

If you would like to count only consecutive duplicates this piece of code may help you:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input = "Hello hello hello Hello";

    vector<pair<string, int>> wordCount;

    for (string::size_type p = 0; p < input.size(); )
    {
        const auto p2 = input.find_first_of(' ', p);

        const auto word = input.substr(p, (p == string::npos) ? string::npos : (p2 - p));

        if (wordCount.empty() || wordCount.back().first != word)
            wordCount.push_back(make_pair(word, 1));
        else
            ++wordCount.back().second;

        if (p2 == string::npos)
            break;

        p = p2 + 1;
    }

    for (const auto& it : wordCount)
        if (it.second > 1)
            std::cout << it.first << " " << it.second << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

This code does not use a map because a single word can have different counts depending on its location ("a a b a a a" would output "a 2" and "a 3")

Both examples scan the string word by word with ' ' as the delimiter. You could specify multiple delimiters in find_first_of if you would like to split your string by tab or dot. (input.find_first_of(" \t.", p))

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am restricted from using maps for this assignment. I should have posted that in my header

Comment: Well, now that you have the code for counting words, figure out how to store it correctly...

Comment: @Andreas this may be a dumb question but in your second block in the first line of the for loop where const auto p2 is assigned to findfirstof() it is marked as a constant but in the second line you have p2-p. Why doesn't this generate a syntax error? I thought const variables can't be modified?

Comment: @Hikari: p2 is const, but the expression `(p2-p)` does not change the value of p2 so it is perfectly ok. It would be an error if I'd write `(p2 -= p)`.